# Can I create a generic GroupBy() in C# LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, generics, .net-5

I am trying to modify the a generic IQueryable extension method to perform a GroupBy operation.  The method I have performs a generic Where on a dynamically defined column:

```
        public static IQueryable<TEntity> WhereById<TEntity, TKey>(
                       this IQueryable<TEntity> query, TKey value, string colName)
            where TEntity : class
        {
            var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "e");
            var propAccess = Expression.PropertyOrField(param, colName);
            var valExpr = Expression.Constant(value);
   
            BinaryExpression predicate;
            predicate = Expression.Equal(propAccess, valExpr);
            var predicateLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(predicate, param);
            return query.Where(predicateLambda);
        }
```

This works perfectly as in:

```
IQueryable<TEntity> entities = _crudApiDbContext.Set<TEntity>()
                    .WhereById<TEntity, int>(id, selectField);
```

Now I need a generic GroupBy().  I am trying the following:

```
        public static IQueryable<TEntity> GroupBy<TEntity>(this IQueryable<TEntity> query, string colName)
            where TEntity : class
        {
            var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "e");
            var propAccess = Expression.PropertyOrField(param, colName);

            BinaryExpression predicate;
            predicate = Expression.XXX(propAccess);  <=what should XXX be?
            var predicateLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, int>>(propAccess);
            return (IQueryable<TEntity>)query.GroupBy(predicateLambda);
        }
```

and I guess my question is what should XXX be?  Or maybe because GroupBy() is an extension method the approach needs to be different?

***Update***
There is a lot of interest as to why I need this - I am building a generic Blazor form for faceted browsing.  So I have a generic method for filtered and sorted search, but I also need to know for certain columns with options, how many options remain after applying the search conditions.  To that end I will perform a GroupBy on each of those columns with the IQueryable which has the search conditions applied to it.  Example of faceted search:
[image]

Comment: Are you reinventing DynamicLinq?

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comment.  I am creating specific functions for a lightweight Azure Functions implementation.

Comment: It is easy to create dynamic GroupBy, but what you plan to do with that? Probably dynamic aggregations?

Comment: Note that `GroupBy` returns not `IQueryable<TEntity>`, it returns `IQueryable<IGrouping<TKey, TEntity>>`, where `TKey` is type of column you group by.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv, I have added an explanation of what I plan to do with this.  Can you describe the easy solution please?

Comment: Give me several minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is solution how to do grouping by dynamic field. Since we don't know type of grouping key, I've decided to make it as `object`.

```cs
public static class QueryableExtensions
{
    static Expression MakePropPath(Expression objExpression, string path)
    {
        return path.Split('.').Aggregate(objExpression, Expression.PropertyOrField);
    }

    public static IQueryable<IGrouping<object, TEntity>> GroupBy<TEntity>(this IQueryable<TEntity> query, string colName)
        where TEntity : class
    {
        var param      = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "e");
        var propAccess = MakePropPath(param, colName);

        var keyLambda = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Convert(propAccess, typeof(object)), param);

        var groupCall = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), nameof(Queryable.GroupBy),
            new[] { typeof(TEntity), typeof(object) }, query.Expression,
            keyLambda);

        return query.Provider.CreateQuery<IGrouping<object, TEntity>>(groupCall);
    }
}
```

Usage is simple in your case:

```cs
var result = query.GroupBy("Genre")
    .Select(g => new 
    {
        g.Key,
        Count = g.Count()
    })
    .ToList();
```